# NumPy: argsort to give row-only permutation?

Tags: python, numpy

I can use `np.argsort()` to create a permutation which if used as an indexing expression returns elements in order:

```
>>> a = np.array([9, 3, 5, 2, 5, 1, 0, 8])
>>> idx = np.argsort(a)
>>> a[idx]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 8, 9])
```

All well and good. Now I want to use this technique on a matrix, to give a permutation which if used for indexing would select the rows in order. Note that I don't want the results of applying `argsort()` on axis 0, as this gives a permutation per column.

In other words,

```
>>> a = np.array([7, 3, 4, 7, 9, 7, 3, 4, 5]).reshape((3,3))
>>> a
array([[7, 3, 4],
       [7, 9, 7],
       [3, 4, 5]])
>>> np.find_lexicographic_row_permutation(a) # pseudo-code
array([2, 0, 1])
```

In other words, the partition would reorder the matrix's rows in 'lexicographic' order.

How can I achieve this in a generic way?

Comment: Tried np.lexsort()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.lexsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) to solve that:

```
row_permutation = np.lexsort(a.T[::-1])
```

We use the transpose because `np.lexsort()` sorts the data by columns, and you want to sort the rows lexicographically.

Comment: Ugh... so if I want to generalise this to ndim=3 (or 4 or 5..)?

Comment: @xpqz , I am not sure if it can be easily solved with higher dimensions.